# Obfuscate segment key in rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a route `users/:id`, where id = 1. Pretty standard, but I would like to change this route to the following:

`/account`

Where any logged in user, in this case a user with an id = 1, does not see their uid as the segment key, but instead a generic 'account' URI only. How can I achieve this in a rails 3 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a route to a standard action which functions as a users own show action. E.g.: you create an action where you get the current user's information and make it shown. The current user can be extracted from the session as usual, so no need for sending out the user id in the url. And you only need a route which redirects `/account` to this action.

Comment: ha! That make sense. I was hoping more for a way to do something like `get 'account', to: "users#show", on: :member`. Which did not work for me as it gives you `users/:id/account`

Comment: You need to manually extract the current user from the session. But otherwise it is quite simple.